# Secure ejabberd: protocol options and ciphers setting has no effect

Tags: configuration, openssl, ejabberd

I try to secure my ejabberd by configuring openssl ciphers like this for s2s communication:

```
{s2s_use_starttls, required}.
{s2s_certfile, "/etc/ejabberd/mycert.pem"}.
{s2s_protocol_options, ["no_sslv3", "no_sslv2"]}.
{s2s_ciphers, "HIGH" }.
```

However the [test shows the server still serves RC4 and sslv3](https://xmpp.net/result.php?id=158487). Why do these settings not show any effect?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `ejabberd 2.1.11-1ubuntu2.1 amd64`. See https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/954